# File Not Found Exception in Android Studio and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

I am a newbee to Android Studio and Kotlin.  I am trying to create a text file using this function below:

```
fun writeTextFile()
{

    try {
        val fileName = "/Downloads/test.text"
        //created a file Object
        val file = File(fileName)
        file.writeText("This is a text file")
    } catch( e: IOException  ) {

    }
}
```

I am expecting a file to be created, but I get an exception error, unable to find the file.

Comment: That is not a valid filesystem location. Books and courses on Android app development will show places you can read and write, such as `getFilesDir()` on `Context`. I cover file I/O in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack).

Answer (score 1):

I guess what do you want to do is getting file from Download folder on android  phone. If the answer is Yes, you need to do this, to directing path into Download's folder.

```
val fileName = File("${requireContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)}/test.text")
```